# document on hover not working jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two buttons and two list. This is my code code:

```js
$(document).on('hover','.select-user-type-js',function(){
            if($(this).hasClass('select-user-type_customer')){
                $('#buyer').show();
                $('#seller').hide();
                $($this).addClass('active');
                $('.select-user-type_performer').removeClass('active');
            }
            else{
                $('#buyer').hide();
                $('#seller').show();
                $($this).addClass('active');
                $('.select-user-type_customer').removeClass('active');
            }
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <a href="" class="select-user-type-js select-user-type_customer active">Customer</a>
        <a href="" id="seller" class="select-user-type-js select-user-type_performer">Seller</a>

    <ul id="buyer">
       <li><a href="#">Menu for buyer #1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Menu for buyer #2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Menu for buyer #3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="seller" style="display: none;">
       <li><a href="#">Menu for seller #1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Menu for seller #2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Menu for seller #3</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I need on hover buttons change specific menu for seller or buyer. How I can do it? My code is not working..

Comment: You might have a spelling error here `$($this)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have 2 `id="seller"`. An id should always be unique.

Second, you should use `mouseenter`.

Third, you have a spelling error in `$($this)` it should be `$(this)`

```js
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.select-user-type-js', function() {
  $('.select-user-type-js.active').add($(this)).toggleClass('active');
  if ($(this).hasClass('select-user-type_customer')) {
    $('#buyer').show();
    $('#seller').hide();
  } else {
    $('#buyer').hide();
    $('#seller').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" class="select-user-type-js select-user-type_customer active">Customer</a>
<a href="" class="select-user-type-js select-user-type_performer">Seller</a>
<ul id="buyer">
  <li><a href="#">Menu for buyer #1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu for buyer #2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu for buyer #3</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="seller" style="display: none;">
  <li><a href="#">Menu for seller #1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu for seller #2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu for seller #3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But can you please tell me, how I can write to cookie menu? When user reload to page, to save the menu that he chose, when clicking to button..?

Comment: Keep in mind that StackOverflow is not a coding service, so you have to try yourself and when you are stuck then ask for help here, also that is the only way to learn it yourself. Just like you did on this question

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="" id="seller" class="select-user-type-js select-user-type_performer">Seller</a>
           ---^^^^^^^-----

<ul id="seller" style="display: none;">
    ---^^^^^^^-----
  <li><a href="#">Menu for seller #1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu for seller #2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu for seller #3</a></li>
</ul>
```

In above code you have duplicate ID values for `DOM` and `DOM` must have unique `ID` values. So try giving different `IDs` to `DOM`. It will work.

Also remove inline style from second `UL`.

**JSFIDDLE LINK :** https://jsfiddle.net/dipeshbeckham/qq617gs5/4/

Comment: sir nice answer... :-)

Comment: @ParthRaval Thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

plese try mouseover with jQuery on function.

```
$(document).on('mouseover','.select-user-type-js',function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('select-user-type_customer')){
            $('#buyer').show();
            $('#seller').hide();
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $('.select-user-type_performer').removeClass('active');
        }
        else{
            $('#buyer').hide();
            $('#seller').show();
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $('.select-user-type_customer').removeClass('active');
        }
 });
```

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $this is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".select-user-type_customer").hover(function() {
    $('#buyer').show();
    $('#seller').hide();
}, function() {
    $('#buyer').show();
    $('#seller').hide();
});

$(".select-user-type_performer").hover(function() {
    $('#buyer').hide();
    $('#seller').show();
}, function() {
    $('#buyer').show();
    $('#seller').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" class="select-user-type-js select-user-type_customer active">Customer</a>
<a href="" class="select-user-type-js select-user-type_performer">Seller</a>
<ul id="buyer">
   <li><a href="#">Menu for buyer #1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Menu for buyer #2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Menu for buyer #3</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="seller" style="display: none;">
   <li><a href="#">Menu for seller #1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Menu for seller #2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Menu for seller #3</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can use class selector element when the mouse pointer hovers over it: